# Good words describing an action taken place after another

Tags: word-choice

What are some good words that can be used to describe an action which has taken place after another?

Example: We baked the cakes. ***After that***, we left the house.

I'm looking for some alternatives for the `After that`

Thanks.

Comment: [After that](http://thesaurus.com/browse/after%20that) in a thesaurus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some words that come to mind are 'subsequently' 'then', and 'later'.